# how is reduce defined (using foreach)

Tags: iteration, jq

I'm having hard time understanding how to use `foreach`. I kinda "understands" the text, but the example given in manual is little bit over my head. Can you please show me how to define `reduce` operation using `foreach`?

Comment: why negative voting? Manual itself says, that foreach is generalized reduce. So I'd like to know how to write reduce using foreach to understand it. Should be easy! yet is completely incomprehensible to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reduce SOURCE as $VAR (INIT; REDUCTION)
```

is equivalent to

```
[ foreach SOURCE as $VAR (INIT; REDUCTION; .) ] | last
```

Conversely,

```
foreach SOURCE as $VAR (INIT; UPDATE; EXTRACT)
```

is equivalent to

```
reduce SOURCE as $VAR (
   { state: ( INIT ), rv: [] };
   .state |= ( UPDATE ) |
   .rv += [ .state | EXTRACT ]
) | .rv[]
```

A you can see, they are very similar. Practically identical, in fact.

- Use `reduce` when you want a single result.
- Use `foreach` when you want a result for each input.

---

For example, say we have the following input:

```json
["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno"]
```

```
foreach .[] as $var (false; not; .)
```

produces

```
true
false
true
false
true
```

so

```
foreach .[] as $var (false; not; if . then $var else empty end)
```

produces

```
"abc"
"ghi"
"mno"
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! If you can (or someone) it would be great if this can be added to manual, as these operation can be challenging for someone new-er to functional world.

Comment: I disagree. This is not the way to go about explaining them. First of all, the manual isn't a tutorial, and tutorial for `reduce` would look more like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65394512/1) (minus the part mentioning `foreach`).

Comment: anyways your explanation here helped me, while sole example from manual with "array of arrays" used as a state to work with was less friendly example — for me. Thanks again for helping me!

Comment: `foreach` is in some ways best understood procedurally, first because the procedural explanation is simple, and secondly because it's accurate -- as can be seen by considering `foreach` expressions that include `break` statements.